# Jquery mobile Panel Error on PAGE CHANGE

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, menu, panel

I am using Jquery mobile and i have a Panel inside every PAGE and when i navigate between pages the panel get blocked : it does not show or work anymore and it blow my style

Any suggestions .. ??

i m using Jquery mobile 1.4 alpha 2

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-alpha.2.js"></script>
```

and this is one page , all pages looks like this pages just the ID of page is different

```
<!-- Start of Page: #Identification -->
<div data-role="page" id="identification" >
<div data-role="panel" data-position-fixed="true" data-theme="a" id="nav-panel">
        <ul data-role="none" data-theme="a" class="nav-search">
            <li class="meteo">
                <span id="date">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="day" rowspan="2">04</th>
                            <td class="month">JUILLET</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="year">2013</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </span>
                <span id="meteo-stat" class="meteo-icon sun">22°</span>

                <div id="blockPhoto">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="enregistrez votre photo" class="photo" onClick="changePhoto();">
                        <span id="image_profil">
                        <span id="txt">enregistrez<br>votre photo</span>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div id="blockPhotoProfil">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Profil" class="photo">
                        <span id="image_profil_client">                         
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </div>

            </li>             
            <li class="commanderTaxi"><a href="#commande" title="commander un taxi">commander un taxi</a></li>
            <li class="reservationEnCours"><a href="#reservation" title="réservation en cours">réservation en cours</a></li>
            <li class="monProfil"><a href="#profil" title="mon profil">mon profil</a></li>              
            <li class="informationLegals"><a href="#informationslegales" title="information légals">information légals</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /panel -->
    <div id="header" data-role="header" data-theme="f" data-position="fixed">
            <span id="logo"><h1><img src="images/logo.png" title="logo" alt="logo"></h1></span>
        <a class="menuButton" data-role="button" href="#nav-panel" data-iconpos="notext"><img class="iconMenu" src="images/btn_menu_OFF.png"></a>

    </div><!-- /header -->          

    <div data-role="content" id="identification-contenu">

         <div id="indentification">
                <div class="titre-identification"><span class="centerV">identification</span></div>
                <div class="s-identifier"><span class="centerV2">S'identifier</span></div>
                <div class="email-identification">E-mail</div> 
                <div class="input-email"> <input type="email" name="email"></div>
                <div class="password-identification">Mot de Passe</div>
                <div class="input-password"><input type="password" name="passe"></div>
                <div class="oublier-identification"><a href="#">Mot de passe oublié</a></div>
                <div class="button-style"><a href="#"><span class="centerV4">Se connecter</span></a></div>
                <div class="creer-compte"><span class="centerV2">CRÉER UN COMPTE</span></div>
                <div class="button-style2"><a href="#"><span class="centerV5">Créer</span></a></div>
           </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /content -->
```

Comment: without code, no one can predict the problem.

Comment: i m using simple jquery mobile panel for a lot of pages (role=page) it get blocked !

Comment: ok, post markup of one page. what version of jQM and jQ are you using..etc...

Comment: Yes , even with Different ID names it have same problem :/

Comment: What version of jQ are you using? Make sure all tags are closed properly.

Comment: Jquery 1.8.2 <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script> 
and all my div are closed properly :(

Comment: use these libraries `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-beta.1.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-beta.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I used it now, the panel is always shown and the MENU button escaped :(

Comment: Dont forget that you're using alpha and beta versions of jQM. Use stable version of jQM http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2013/07/19/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-3-2/#download

Comment: Okei omar thank you very much brother, i will try to change to a stable version, please if an example of page multi panel work for you please i will be glad if you share it with me

Comment: in 1.3.2 you have have two panels in each page. it's easy and straightforward. http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/panels/

Comment: Thank you deeply, i m working on it , i ll be back if i found problems :p Gracias amigo :))

Comment: Buena suerte! de nada amigo ;)

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

The 1.3.2 and the 1.9.1 Worked sooo fine for me

Man you are amazing +1 +1 +1 +1 Goooood advices and help thank you very muuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuch

Solved